# Android app crashes with recycler view

Tags: android, crash, android-recyclerview

I have searched through all the web but didn't find any solution. I am grabbing the data from online database and showing in recycler view but unfortunately app carshes. I don't know why. I have attached all the logcat and my relevant code is attached as well. Any help will be greatly appreciated.

```
E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
                  Process: com.example.liger.admin_panel, PID: 28935
                  java.lang.NullPointerException
                      at android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView$Adapter.createViewHolder(RecyclerView.java:6368)
                      at android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView$Recycler.tryGetViewHolderForPositionByDeadline(RecyclerView.java:5555)
                      at android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView$Recycler.getViewForPosition(RecyclerView.java:5440)
                      at android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView$Recycler.getViewForPosition(RecyclerView.java:5436)
                      at android.support.v7.widget.LinearLayoutManager$LayoutState.next(LinearLayoutManager.java:2224)
                      at android.support.v7.widget.LinearLayoutManager.layoutChunk(LinearLayoutManager.java:1551)
                      at android.support.v7.widget.LinearLayoutManager.fill(LinearLayoutManager.java:1511)
                      at android.support.v7.widget.LinearLayoutManager.onLayoutChildren(LinearLayoutManager.java:595)
                      at android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView.dispatchLayoutStep2(RecyclerView.java:3583)
                      at android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView.onMeasure(RecyclerView.java:3025)
                      at android.view.View.measure(View.java:16539)
                      at android.widget.RelativeLayout.measureChild(RelativeLayout.java:689)
                      at android.widget.RelativeLayout.onMeasure(RelativeLayout.java:473)
                      at android.view.View.measure(View.java:16539)
                      at android.view.ViewGroup.measureChildWithMargins(ViewGroup.java:5140)
                      at android.widget.FrameLayout.onMeasure(FrameLayout.java:310)
                      at android.support.v7.widget.ContentFrameLayout.onMeasure(ContentFrameLayout.java:139)
                      at android.view.View.measure(View.java:16539)
                      at android.view.ViewGroup.measureChildWithMargins(ViewGroup.java:5140)
                      at android.support.v7.widget.ActionBarOverlayLayout.onMeasure(ActionBarOverlayLayout.java:393)
                      at android.view.View.measure(View.java:16539)
                      at android.view.ViewGroup.measureChildWithMargins(ViewGroup.java:5140)
                      at android.widget.FrameLayout.onMeasure(FrameLayout.java:310)
                      at android.view.View.measure(View.java:16539)
                      at android.view.ViewGroup.measureChildWithMargins(ViewGroup.java:5140)
                      at android.widget.LinearLayout.measureChildBeforeLayout(LinearLayout.java:1406)
                      at android.widget.LinearLayout.measureVertical(LinearLayout.java:697)
                      at android.widget.LinearLayout.onMeasure(LinearLayout.java:590)
                      at android.view.View.measure(View.java:16539)
                      at android.view.ViewGroup.measureChildWithMargins(ViewGroup.java:5140)
                      at android.widget.FrameLayout.onMeasure(FrameLayout.java:310)
                      at com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneWindow$DecorView.onMeasure(PhoneWindow.java:2421)
                      at android.view.View.measure(View.java:16539)
                      at android.view.ViewRootImpl.performMeasure(ViewRootImpl.java:1959)
                      at android.view.ViewRootImpl.measureHierarchy(ViewRootImpl.java:1155)
                      at android.view.ViewRootImpl.performTraversals(ViewRootImpl.java:1337)
                      at android.view.ViewRootImpl.doTraversal(ViewRootImpl.java:1042)
                      at android.view.ViewRootImpl$TraversalRunnable.run(ViewRootImpl.java:5891)
                      at android.view.Choreographer$CallbackRecord.run(Choreographer.java:761)
                      at android.view.Choreographer.doCallbacks(Choreographer.java:574)
                      at android.view.Choreographer.doFrame(Choreographer.java:544)
                      at android.view.Choreographer$FrameDisplayEventReceiver.run(Choreographer.java:747)
                      at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:733)
                      at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:95)
                      at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:136)
                      at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5103)
                      at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
                      at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:515)
                      at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:790)
                      at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:606)
                      at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

RecyclerView class code

```
package com.example.liger.admin_panel;

import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.support.v7.widget.LinearLayoutManager;
import android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.ProgressBar;
import android.widget.Toast;

import com.android.volley.RequestQueue;
import com.android.volley.Response;
import com.android.volley.VolleyError;
import com.android.volley.toolbox.JsonArrayRequest;
import com.android.volley.toolbox.Volley;

import org.json.JSONArray;
import org.json.JSONException;
import org.json.JSONObject;

import java.util.ArrayList;

public class recycler_view extends AppCompatActivity{

    RecyclerView recyclerView;
    RecyclerView.Adapter adapter;
//    RecyclerView.LayoutManager layoutManager;

    ArrayList<items>item;
    RequestQueue requestQueue;
    //int requestCount = 1;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_recycler_view);


        final LinearLayoutManager layoutManager = new LinearLayoutManager(this);
        layoutManager.setOrientation(LinearLayoutManager.HORIZONTAL);
        recyclerView = (RecyclerView) findViewById(R.id.recyclerView);
        recyclerView.setLayoutManager(layoutManager);

        recyclerView.setHasFixedSize(true);

        item = new ArrayList<items>();
        requestQueue = Volley.newRequestQueue(this);

        getData();

      //  recyclerView.setOnScrollChangeListener(this);

        adapter = new itemsAdapter(item, getApplicationContext());
        recyclerView.setAdapter(adapter);
    }

    private void getData() {
        requestQueue.add(getDataFromServer());
       // requestCount++;
    }

    private JsonArrayRequest getDataFromServer() {
        final ProgressBar progressBar = (ProgressBar) findViewById(R.id.progressBar1);

        progressBar.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
        progressBar.setIndeterminate(true);

        JsonArrayRequest jsonArrayRequest = new JsonArrayRequest(constants.get_items,
                new Response.Listener<JSONArray>() {
                    @Override
                    public void onResponse(JSONArray response) {
                        parseData(response);
                        progressBar.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                    }
                },
                new Response.ErrorListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error) {
                        progressBar.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "No More Items Available", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                    }
                });
        return jsonArrayRequest;
    }

    private void parseData(JSONArray array){
        for (int i = 0; i < array.length(); i++){
            JSONObject json= null;
            try {

                json = array.getJSONObject(i);
                items obj = new items(json.getString("item_name"),
                                      json.getString("item_category"),
                                      json.getString("item_price"),
                                      json.getString("item_rating"),
                                      constants.img_url+json.getString("item_img"));

                item.add(obj);

            } catch (JSONException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
        adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
    }

    private boolean isLastItemDisplaying(RecyclerView recyclerView){
        if (recyclerView.getAdapter().getItemCount() != 0) {
            int lastVisibleItemPosition = ((LinearLayoutManager) recyclerView.getLayoutManager()).findLastCompletelyVisibleItemPosition();
            if (lastVisibleItemPosition != recyclerView.NO_POSITION &&lastVisibleItemPosition == recyclerView.getAdapter().getItemCount() - 1)
                return true;
        }
        return false;
    }

}
```

ItemsAdapter Class code

```
package com.example.liger.admin_panel;

import android.content.Context;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.widget.ImageView;
import android.widget.RatingBar;
import android.widget.TextView;

import com.bumptech.glide.Glide;

import java.util.ArrayList;

/**
 * Created by liger on 4/30/2017.
 */

public class itemsAdapter extends android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView.Adapter<itemsAdapter.ItemViewHolder> {

    ArrayList<items>item = new ArrayList<items>();
    Context context;

    public itemsAdapter(ArrayList<items> item, Context ctx) {
        this.item = item;
        this.context = ctx;
    }

    @Override
    public ItemViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {

        View view = LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext()).inflate(R.layout.card_view_layout,parent,false);
        ItemViewHolder itemViewHolder = new ItemViewHolder(view);

        return null;
    }

    @Override
    public void onBindViewHolder(ItemViewHolder holder, int position) {
        items obj = item.get(position);

        Glide.with(this.context).load(obj.getImg_name()).into(holder.item_img);
        holder.item_name.setText(obj.getName());
        holder.item_category.setText(obj.getCategory());
        holder.item_price.setText(obj.getPrice());
        holder.item_rating.setRating(Float.parseFloat(obj.getRating()));
    }

    @Override
    public int getItemCount() {
        return item.size();
    }

    public static class ItemViewHolder extends android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView.ViewHolder{

        ImageView item_img;
        TextView item_name,item_price,item_category;
        RatingBar item_rating;

        public ItemViewHolder(View itemView)
            super(itemView);

            item_img = (ImageView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.card_img);
            item_name = (TextView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.card_name);
            item_price = (TextView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.card_price);
            item_category= (TextView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.card_category);
            item_rating = (RatingBar) itemView.findViewById(R.id.card_rating);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: That's only logcat, please post code also

Comment: There is a relevant classes code below logcat.

Comment: You're returning null in `onCreateViewHolder()`. Return `itemViewHolder` instead.

Comment: Right now You are the love of my life. That fixed my issue. Thanks A lot. @M